# Is there a name for subduction boundaries at the North of Australia?

Tags: geology, plate-tectonics, subduction

I know the ridge at the South of Australia is named Southeast Indian Ridge.

I would like to know if there is a geological name for the three subduction branches that cross indonesian zone, at the North of Australia, as seen in this map.

> [image: Current plate limits from USGS]
>
> Source: [researchgate.net](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Figura-12-Placas-y-dorsales-oceanicas-USGS-US-Geological-Survey_fig2_320286510) Map by [United States Geological Survey](https://www.usgs.gov/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think there is one name for the area. Rather it is a region with multiple plates, namely the Timor Plate, the eastern portion of the Banda Sea Plate, the Maoke Plate and the Woodlark Plate, all of which lie on the Arafura shelf which lies upon the Australian Plate. The Timor trough, Tanimbar Trough and Aru Trough would cover the western portion of the area you are questioning. 
[image: Timor Trough] [image: Tanimbar Trough]
The Papuan Thrust and Fold Belt (PTFB) and the Aure Trough make up the northern and eastern portion of the area in question. Hope this helps. [image: PTFB_Aure]